# É possível comparar valores numéricos em strings sem fazer cast para tipo Number?

Tags: java, comparação

Tenho dois valores numéricos que são recuperados em strings e gostaria de saber se há como compará-los para ver qual valor numérico é maior, mas sem ter que ficar fazendo conversão para tipo `Number` (como `Integer`, `Double` e `Float`).

Exemplo:

```
String strValue01 = "50";
String strValue02 = "62";
```

Há alguma forma de comparar qual número é maior, **sem ter que fazer parse para tipo numérico**? Pensei que pudesse haver algo via valores ASCII, mas não faço ideia de como faz, se for possível.

Comment: Depende do quanto você confia no formato que está. Sempre 2 caracteres, sempre tem um 0 à esquerda se só tiver um dígito significante? Se não, nunca tem o 0 antes? Se pode ser tamanho diferente, tem um máximo?

Comment: @bigown unica confiança que eu tenho é que ambas sempre serão um tipo numérico e sem ponto flutuante. Agora o número de casas pode ser 1 ou 7.

Comment: Eu posso colocar o numero de casas fixas na string, se isso facilitar resolução. O que eu quero é evitar ficar criando variavel int temporaria ou fazer parse pra depois voltar pra string novamente.

Comment: Isso nem tanto, saber um máximo pode ser útil. É mais importante saber se pode ter 0 à esquerda, se terá sempre, ou terá nunca. Se puder ter ou não, complica, mas dá para fazer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso daqui deve funcionar:

```
public static int seuComparador(String a, String b) {
    String c = a;
    String d = b;
    while (c.length() < d.length()) c = "0" + c;
    while (c.length() > d.length()) d = "0" + d;
    return c.compareTo(d);
}
```

Veja aqui um teste:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(seuComparador("0", "3"));
    System.out.println(seuComparador("10", "3"));
    System.out.println(seuComparador("007", "300"));
    System.out.println(seuComparador("40", "040"));
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
-3
1
-3
0
```

Funciona de acordo com o princípio da interface [**`java.util.Comparator`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). Onde:

- Um retorno zero significa strings iguais.
- Um número negativo é quando a primeira antecede a segunda.
- Um número positivo é quando a primeira sucede a segunda.

Ou seja, essa saída significa que 0 é menor que 3, que 10 é maior que 3, que 007 é menor que 300 e que 40 é igual a 040.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/ogjQFf)

---

Entretanto, esse código não é muito eficiente por criar vários objetos intermediários temporários para acrescentar zeros. Uma otimização que já crie todos os zeros necessários uma única vez é possível. Também é possível proceder diretamente para o `compareTo` quando os tamanhos das `String`s forem iguais:

```
public static int seuComparador(String a, String b) {
    int sa = a.length();
    int sb = b.length();
    if (sa == sb) return a.compareTo(b);
    int dif = sa > sb ? sa - sb : sb - sa;

    StringBuilder pad = new StringBuilder(sa > sb ? sa : sb);
    for (int i = 0; i < dif; i++) {
        pad.append('0');
    }

    String c = sa > sb ? a : pad.append(a).toString();
    String d = sa > sb ? pad.append(b).toString() : b;
    return c.compareTo(d);
}
```

Produz a mesma saída do anterior. [**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/DPyAmP)

Comment: Se as duas possuirem sempre o mesmo numero de casas, é possivel reduzir?

Comment: @Articuno Sim. Nesse caso, bastaria usar o método `compareTo` da classe `String` diretamente.

Comment: @VictorStafusa não estou com uma ide para ver o método compareTo agora, mas este método não utiliza algum "cast" dentro dele ?

Comment: @Matheus Não. Não utiliza nenhum cast.

Comment: Deu certo, defini o numero de digitos de cada string como fixo e usei o compare.

Comment: Só tem uma coisa que eu não gostei nessa resposta: se os objetos forem de tamanhos distintos, um novo será alocado. Se houver a garantia de que não há zeros a esquerda, então é possível remover essas adições de zero à esquerda do condicional e simplesmente retornar

Comment: @Matheus não, ele internamente verifica os caracteres das duas strings sem transformá-los

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Resposta editada. :)

Comment: @VictorStafusa deu nem tempo de fazer uma resposta concorrente xD. De toda sorte, você já tinha meu +1

Comment: @VictorStafusa ué, agora sempre cria um novo objeto?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Editada de novo. Acrescentei um `if (sa == sb) return a.compareTo(b);`.